# Difference between .bz2 and .tar.bz2 files

Tags: files, tar, bzip2

I am supposed to find whether a file is compressed using .bz2 or .tar.bz2(without using extension of file) and
and decompress it accordingly. I used the `file` command but it is giving same result for both .bz2 and .tar.bz2. Please suggest a way to identify .bz2 and .tar.bz2 files distinctly.

Comment: By "decompress", do you mean "extract fully if it's a `tar` archive", because both are (probably) files compressed by `bzip2` and would be uncompressed by `bunzip2`. The fact that the uncompressed file is a `tar` archive or something else is not something that would matter to the `bzip2` compressor. I'm confused by what's being asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the file through `bzcat` and pipe the result to `file`:

```
$ bzcat somefile.bz2 | file -
/dev/stdin: data               # or whatever; this is not a .tar.bz2

$ bzcat otherfile.bz2 | file -
/dev/stdin: POSIX tar archive  # this *is* a .tar.bz2
```

Answer (score 1):

`file` wouldn't care: it looks at the *format*, not the *filename*.

The tar-formatted content can only be seen by uncompressing the file.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a version of `file` that supports the `-z` or `-Z` options , you can use either of those to try to look inside compressed files to find out what they are.

Neither option is part of the POSIX spec for [file](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/file.html).

However, the `-z` option has been in the BSD `file` command for a very long time, since the early 2000s at least (the changelog on my system doesn't show anything before 2003).  `-Z` was added in June 2015.    BSD `file` is used on many current systems, including most (all?) Linux distributions, *BSD, and Mac OSX.

From `man file`:

> -z, --uncompress
>
> Try to look inside compressed files.
>
> -Z, --uncompress-noreport
>
> Try to look inside compressed files, but report information about
>     the contents only not the compression.

For example:

```
# make a .tar.bz2 file
tar cfj test.tar.bz2 *

# make a .bz2 file
echo junk | bzip2 -c > junk.bz2

# try to fool `file`
cp test.tar.bz2 test.bz2
cp junk.bz2 junk.tar.bz2

echo "file -z:"
file -z *.bz2

echo
echo

echo "file -Z:"
file -Z *.bz2
```

Output:

```
file -z:
junk.bz2:     ASCII text (bzip2 compressed data, block size = 900k)
junk.tar.bz2: ASCII text (bzip2 compressed data, block size = 900k)
test.bz2:     POSIX tar archive (GNU) (bzip2 compressed data, block size = 900k)
test.tar.bz2: POSIX tar archive (GNU) (bzip2 compressed data, block size = 900k)


file -Z:
junk.bz2:     ASCII text
junk.tar.bz2: ASCII text
test.bz2:     POSIX tar archive (GNU)
test.tar.bz2: POSIX tar archive (GNU)
```